# Free simple TODO app with popups

Tags: windows, gratis, project-management, reminders

I'm looking for a simple TO-DO app that will show popups with the ability to click the link and open a website associated to a task, and will allow for reoccurring tasks.

I've tried some browsers plugins but they don't do popups. No need to sync items, it will be used locally.

Comment: I think this question was asked before on Software Recommendations... I will try to find it! I used [Rainlendar](http://www.rainlendar.net/cms/index.php) few years ago, but I'm not sure if it has popup option.

Answer (score 5):

I am a proud, happy and confident user of [AbstractSpoon ToDo-List](http://www.abstractspoon.com/) and recommend it to all my colleagues.

Your requirements and how they are fulfilled:

- simple: maybe it has too many features by default. So make sure you hide everything you don't need

  [image: AbstractSpoon column configuration]
- popups: turned off by default but configurable in preferences. The information displayed is configurable

  [image: AbstractSpoon Notify me of all tasks due]
- ability to click the link: yes, e.g. in the popup

  [image: AbstractSpoon Clickable link in popup]
- allow for reoccurring tasks: of course

  [image: AbstractSpoon Recurring tasks]
- No need to sync: but would be supported
- used locally: data is saved in a TDL file

Comment: while this is fantastic software and I was an user myself, it's way sophisticated and therefore complicated for what I want to use it for. thanks for recommendation, though

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered just using a Webapp? Take Wunderlist - you can turn on desktop alerts (I can only confirm for Chrome).

## [Wunderlist](https://www.wunderlist.com/home)

> Wunderlist is the easiest way to get stuff done. Whether you’re
> planning a holiday, sharing a shopping list with a partner or managing
> multiple work projects, Wunderlist is here to help you tick off all
> your personal and professional to-dos.

Doesn't get much simpler than this!

[image]

Recurring Tasks...

[image] [image]

Here is a screenshot of the reminder (when used in Chrome) - click anywhere on this and the task will open in the browser. This will pop up, and then about 20/30 seconds later there will be a little chiming noise to alert you. Not too sure why there's the delay...

[image]

This is turned on by going `Account Settings` > `Notifications` then turn on `Push Notifications` and `Desktop Notifications` - I'm not sure which of the two it is, so I have both on just in case! Also make sure that Chrome is allowing notifications.

They also have apps for every platform under the sun:

- Windows 7/8/10
- Mac OS X
- Android Phone & Tablet
- iPhone/iPad
- Web App
- Windows Phone
- Chromebooks
- Blackberry (Apk for Android)
- Browser Extension for Chrome, Safari & Firefox

Comment: I don't see a way to see popup reminders.

Comment: CalvT, could you please post a screenshot of a "popup with a link" as described in the question? Thanks :-)

Comment: In the popup (last screenshot), is that a link that you defined, and that opens in a browser when clicked on?

Comment: @marekp quite late, but take a look at my answer now - let me know if you have any more questions!

Comment: Sorry again but could you put a last screenshot showing where you specify what URL? It is central to the question. Thanks!

Comment: @NicolasRaoul - not a problem - It seems I misunderstood the bit about the url - I supposed `marekp` meant open the task in the browser :/ so no it can't open URLs

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you checkout [Free ToDo List](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5371/ToDoList-An-effective-and-flexible-way-to-keep-on). It's very easy to use, runs locally so you need not worry about privacy issues, and has ability to have various notes and hyperlinks for each task. It supports reminders and recurring tasks. However it does not really show popups - only reminder popups.

Comment: again, too complicated. I have Outlook 2013 for this type of stuff